# Turbo Prolog's 'save' analogue in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, save, swi-prolog, fact, turbo-prolog

Is there any SWI's analogue for Turbo's **save** function, which saves into a file facts, previously loaded via **consult** and then appended via **assert**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've not found any save-like functions in manual. May be try the following replacement:

```
% Save whole DB into file
save(FileName) :-
  open(FileName, update, F),
  with_output_to(S, listing),
  close(F).
```

Or even shorter:

```
save(FileName) :-
  tell(FileName), listing, told.
```